# Distribute Silverlight Out of Browser with GPO, launch from virtual SSO desktop?

Tags: silverlight, single-sign-on, out-of-browser, gpo

We have a Silverlight 5 app, with in and out-of-browser versions. The out-of-browser version is used to provide elevated rights, where accesses to local resources are needed.

Now we are facing installing the out-of-browser app in typical hospital environments. Here we have first of all, centralized deployments through GPO or other mechanisms. The second thing is providing scriptable links to single sign-on platforms that usually replaces to normal desktop with a launchpad of services available to the user. Direct access to physical c-drive might also be prevented.

As we know, the normal desktop link for a OOB SL-app is an unique parameter for sllauncher.exe.

How do you start to support deployment and installation of your app in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install your XAP as an Out-Of-Browser application using a script to invoke `sllauncher` like this:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Silverlight\sllauncher.exe" 
/install:"C:\temp\MyApp.xap" 
/origin:http://www.mysite.com/ClientBin/MyApp.xap  
/shortcut:desktop+startmenu  /overwrite
```

The XAP needs to be available locally for this to work. (I haven't tried it from a network share.)